# Invalid singnature in quickbooks authentication

Tags: apex, quickbooks, quickbooks-api

```
    Hi i am trying to create query to quickbook but getting invalid signature

    can anybody help me where 

    public class class1 {
            public class1()
            {
                string consumersecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
                string consumerkey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
                  String endpoint='https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token';

        string s1=string.valueof(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);

        String nonce = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
        String algorithmName = 'HMAC-SHA1';
        Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName,Blob.valueOf(consumersecret),Blob.valueOf(consumerkey));
        String signature12 =EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
        string Signature1=EncodingUtil.urlencode(signature12,'UTF-8');


        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+Signature1);
        Http http=new Http();
        HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();

        String body = String.format(
    'oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_signature_method={1}&oauth_signature={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_nonce={4}&oauth_version={5}&oauth_callback={6}',
    new String[] {
        consumerkey,    // the key
        'HMAC-SHA1',    // the method
        Signature1,     // the signature
        s1,             // the timestamp
        nonce,          // the nonce
        '1.0',
        'http://salesforce.com'}          // the version
);
req.setBody(body);

        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');   
        HttpResponse res;
        res = http.send(req); 
        system.debug(res.getbody());     



            } }

thanks in advance..
```

Comment: hey did you find the solution to your problem please share ?

Comment: Hi @faddee, let me check